# personal view setting in sharepoint list

Tags: list, view, sharepoint-2010

is it possible that once configured in advance , we can block the create personal view settings in share point server list.

Please share your experience.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible to  remove "Manage Personal Views" option from Permissions Level. I'm not sure what is required. My experience is,  to create new permission level and modify the settings on the newly created one. If you want to restrict permission to view then you have to use Sharepoint designer to edit the view ( I mean without coding). Hope this helps.